# How can I validate mer. 1 mai 2019 button?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am using Eclipse(java) with Selenium. Cannot validate button when clicking on  May 1st 2019 button (entry).

I have used this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("gws-travel-calendar__day-label")).click();
```

and this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@className,'gws-travel-calendar__day-label')][contains(input, '1')]")).click();
```

This image shows the calendar and the div:
[image]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the element

Comment: You don't see the text on the screenshot?

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `driver.findElement(By.className("gws-travel-calendar__day-label")).click();`

   this locator is not unique it has 365 matching nodes with that class name so in lay mans term selenium confused where to click
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@className,'gws-travel-calendar__day-label')][contains(input, '1')]")).click();`

   this xpath you mentioned is not correct, only one attribute of tag can be used at a time like `@class` or `@name` , contains method has different syntax than what you have used contains can work in following ways

   `//div[contains(text(),"text to verify")]`
   `//div[contains(@name,"value of name attribute")]`
   `//div[contains(@class,"value of class attribute")]`
3. you can find element using this xpath as

   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//calendar-day[@data-day="2019-05-01"]")).click();`

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//calendar-day[@data-day="2019-05-01"]")).click();  **Does not wotk**

Comment: what error you are getting? have you tried it? why its not working?